# Help With Complex Numbers in Polar Form in the Context of AC Voltages

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, complex-numbers, inductance

I'm learning about AC right now, and I think I've got an OK grasp of complex numbers (not in their polar form, though), but I don't understand this step in a derivation at all:

$$V_i=V_0e^{j\omega t}$$
$$I=\frac{V_0e^{j\omega t}}{Z}$$
$$I=\frac{V_0e^{j\omega t}}{|Z| \angle \theta}$$
$$I=\frac{V_0}{|Z|} \angle (\omega t - \theta)$$

I don't understand how my professor went from line 3 to line 4 in the above derivation.

Comment: hint:$\angle \theta = e^{j\theta}$ and $Z=|Z|e^{j\theta}$

Comment: Mixing exponential notation and that angle thingy *in the same expression* seems weird. And it seems like the last expression needs $\omega t-\theta$ to be in parentheses.

Comment: @Ghoster I agree, it's really weird. That's part of why it's so weird to me. Also, yes. You're right, the $\omega t - \theta$ should be in parentheses. I'll fix that right now.

Comment: @hyportnex I don't doubt your answer, but this seems a little counter intuitive to me... why is $\angle \theta = e^{j \theta}$? I thought $e^{j \theta} = cos(\theta) + i sin(\theta)$?

Comment: How did your professor define the angle notation?

Comment: Why did you write $e^{j\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ with a $j$ on the left and an $i$ on the right? Does your professor not use a consistent choice for the imaginary unit?

Comment: Just rewrite $\angle \theta=\cos\theta + j \sin \theta=e^{j\theta}$ (by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)) (where $j=\sqrt{-1}$) and follow your nose. At the end, you should get a factor of $e^{j(\omega t - \theta)}$, which you can then rewrite as $\angle (\omega t - \theta)$ (by definition). I think you are probably just getting tripped up by the $\angle$ notation.

Comment: @Ghoster I wrote $e^{j \theta} = cos\theta + i sin\theta$ because my professor uses $i$, but from what I've read online, a lot more people seem to be using $j$, so I put that in my question instead of $i$. I guess I kind of just forgot halfway through, though, that I switched

Comment: @Andrew Thank you very much for your answer! I'm still stuck on the same point though...why is $\angle \theta = cos\theta + j sin\theta$? Why isn't it just $\angle \theta = \theta$?

Comment: In the U.S., physicists mostly use $i$ but I think electrical engineers often use $j$.

Comment: You’re asking about the definition of a notation. How can your professor be using a notation without defining what it means? If $\angle\theta$ were just $\theta$, what would be the point of the $\angle$? The notation means a unit “vector” in the complex plane at angle $\theta$.

Comment: @JBatswani Think of $\angle(\theta)$ as being a function. You'd have no problem if I told you that $f(\theta)=e^{j\theta}$. Similarly there's no issue defining $\angle(\theta)=e^{j\theta}$. For purely notational reasons -- nothing deep, just laziness -- sometimes people don't put any brackets so they write $\angle \theta = e^{j\theta}$. There's nothing deep there, it's just a shorthand.

Comment: @Andrew thanks again for your kind comment. Everything makes sense now, and I just have one final question: if $\angle \theta = e^{i \theta}$, why is a complex number, such as $Z$, equal to its modulus times this function, $|Z| e^{i \theta}$? Thanks again!

Comment: @JBatswani This is known as the polar form of a complex number, and you can read about it in any text that covers complex numbers, such as [this one](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Precalculus/Precalculus_1e_(OpenStax)/08%3A_Further_Applications_of_Trigonometry/8.05%3A_Polar_Form_of_Complex_Numbers).

Comment: Think of complex numbers as *vectors* (from the origin to a point in the complex plane) with a real component and an imaginary component. A vector can be written as a magnitude (length) times a unit vector. The $|Z|$ is the magnitude; the $e^{i\theta}$ is the unit vector (with real component $\cos\theta$ and imaginary component $\sin\theta$).